# Load a plugin via Lazy Load / Ajax

Tags: wordpress, plugins, lazy-loading

Hy,
i have a storelocator-plugin for wordpress with about 700 entries and this slow down my site for too long.

Is it possible to lazy load a plugin or show the section after it's ready loaded.

Any idea?

thx

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the plugin and provide a short example of how it's currently being loaded

Comment: http://www.shark-ecigarette.at/#storelocator

Comment: I've tried to install ajaxify and a lazy loading tool to lazy load it by id but nothing helped.

Comment: I meant could you add an example of the html that loads the plugin currently(the script tag), and the javascript code that initializes the plugin. If you can't find that out at least a link to the exact plugin that your using would be helpful

Comment: http://www.flippercode.com/product/wc-store-locator/

Comment: It would be easier if theres a plugin where i can 
[ajax] [storelocator] [/ajax]

Comment: So i've checked what is taking so much time to initialise:

[code][/code]

Answer (score 0):

So i've checked what is taking so much time to initialise:

public function _wsl_load_scripts_frontend() {

```
        $options = get_option( '_wsl_store_locator_settings' );
        $options = unserialize($options);

        /******************* API Settings *********************/
        $wsl_apikey = ( $options['wsl_apikey'] != "" ) ? sanitize_text_field( $options['wsl_apikey'] ) : '';
        $wsl_map_language = ( $options['wsl_map_language'] != "" ) ? sanitize_text_field( $options['wsl_map_language'] ) : 'en';

        if ( !empty($wsl_apikey) ) 
        {
          if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') 
          $wsl_apilocation = 'https';
          else 
          $wsl_apilocation = 'http';

          $wsl_apilocation .= '://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key='.$wsl_apikey.'&sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&language='.$wsl_map_language;
        }
        else
        {
          if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') 
          $wsl_apilocation = 'https';
          else 
          $wsl_apilocation = 'http';

          $wsl_apilocation .= '://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&language='.$wsl_map_language;
        }

        wp_register_script( 'wsl-maps-api-frontend', $wsl_apilocation );
        wp_register_style( 'wsl-store-locator-css', WPWSL_CSS.'wsl-frontend.css' );
    }
```

Comment: And here is the initialization of this function:

public function _wsl_init()

Comment: So i think my problem is now: how can i load a function (_wsl_init()) via ajax